# AppFabric Caching: ErrorCode<ERRCA0017>:SubStatus<ES0001>:There is a temporary failure. Please retry later

Tags: caching, appfabric

We have a 3 machine cache cluster running with SQL configuration provider. The service is running under a domain account on the cache hosts (We are not using Security). The SQL server is also running under the a domain user account. We had issues with caching service running under Network Service and could not connect to SQL at all. But this configuration allowed the cluster to be up and running smoothly.

There are 2 types of cache clients. One of the cache clients is a native c++ exe running under the same domain account that the cache service runs on. These cache clients are on different machines. All such clients can successfully connect to the cache host.

The second type of a cache client is a .NET web application that runs under Network Service. This client is unable to write/fetch anything into the cache host. It is able successfully initialize the cache factory but fails with :

```
`Creating Region for general use in default cache

Error in Cache Call : ErrorCode<ERRCA0017>:SubStatus<ES0001>:There is a temporary     failure. Please retry later. : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=164049
at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.ThrowException(ResponseBody respBody)
at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.CreateRegion(String region)
at CacheAPISample.Program.CreateRegion(String myRegion)
at CacheAPISample.Program.RunSampleTest()
at CacheAPISample.Program.Main(String[] args)`
```

From the error description there is no indication of what kind of error would this be. I have made sure the domain\clientmachinename$ is a allowed cache client. Security and Protection are turned off. Firewall rules are enabled (Given client type 1 can successfully call, firewall is ruled out as an issue).

So far I have tried:

1. Running sample tests with a domain user from client type 2. And also making sure the domain user is a allowed cache client.
2. Host mapping the cache server.

What should I do to get down to the actual root cause of the error? The logs at the cache hosts are clean. There are no errors.

Comment: See my answer on this related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859523/appfabric-cache-concurrency-issue/6870353#6870353

Comment: No Frode, I dont have a concurrent Get request issue. The same sample test runs from the client type 1. I have another stack which mimics this setup and there I have everything working. I am running into some weird windows security issue which I am not a expert on.

Comment: Retry later applies to get and update setups. Also note that security is of importance. HOw are your clients setup?

Comment: Security and protection are turned off. The security policies reflect appropriate ACLs are open from client to the cache hosts at 22233 port. Clients also have access to SQL cluster at 1433 port although I am not sure the cache clients directly talk to SQL to read any configuration data. What more information do you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as a followup, I believe this was partly resolved by ensuring that the client system could resolve the AppFabric server by machine name (using etc/hosts hack) not by FQDN.  This appears to be a known issue out there.  Unfortunately the error message is the same for this and other real failures.

Comment: Yes Thanks for updating the thread with the resolution. Hostmapping the cache hosts by machine name worked for us. And yes the error should be a bit more descriptive rather than the generic error that is thrown.